# check if file size doesn't exceed 2GB in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm using this code in node to check if a file isn't starting with a dot

```
if( !file.startsWith('.') ){...}
```

It seems working fine anyway I need to check also if the size of the file isn't greater than 2GB. How I can accomplish this? Something like this will work?

```
if( !file.startsWith('.') || fs.statSync(`${filesPath}${file}`).size < 2048 ){...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to make sure the file does not start with a dot *and* is less than 2GB, this code should do what you want:

```
const GIGABYTE = Math.pow(1024, 3);
const MAX_SIZE = 2 * GIGABYTE;

const filePath = path.join(filesPath, file);
console.log( { filePath });
if (!file.startsWith('.') && fs.statSync(filePath).size <= MAX_SIZE ) {
    console.log("File is below max size and does not start with a dot.")
} else {
    console.log("File is above max size or starts with a dot.")
}
```

You could also split up the logic like so:

```
const filePath = path.join(filesPath, file);
if (file.startsWith(".")) {
    console.log("File starts with a dot.")
} else if (fs.statSync(filePath).size > MAX_SIZE) { 
    console.log("File is above max size.")
} else {
    // File is good
    console.log("File is below max size and does not start with a dot.")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will implement it in my code. Just a question about the `fs.statSync()`, at the moment I'm using the literal string to join the path that is inputted by the user with the filename. The user usually can omit the final slash `/` and this can be a problem, is there a better way to format it?

Comment: You could look at path.join (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths), I'll update the answer. It should mean that the user can either include or omit the final slash, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using [yargs](https://github.com/yargs/yargs) to parse cli arguments, I've used at the moment the `path.format()` but I will try `path.join()` too.